# Integrate a dictionary to all tasks and loop through it in Ansible

Tags: ansible

Hey still kind of new with Ansible.

I made a playbook(test) that will perform a rolling update for a Mariadb galera-cluster that uses a HAproxy as lb.

I have no idea how to use the dictionary(bottom of the code) for all my tasks in the play. Also it has to loop like first server 1 then server 3 then server 2 and then server 4. Idea is that if the host or ip changed that you'll only have to change it in the dictionary.

For example task1 needs to use the key.value of host1 same for task2 and when its done loop to the next host.

I tried to use the vars module but it only worked task 
specific. Was thinking of using the Vars folder but I'm not using the roles architecture.

```
- hosts: DBserver
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: disable the haproxy server
    replace:
      path: /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
      regexp: "{{ item }}"
      replace: 'server "{{}}" "{{}}"  check weight 0'
    with_items:
    - 'server "{{}}" "{{}}"  check weight 1' 

- hosts: "{{}}"
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: stop the mariadb
    service:
      name: mariadb
      state: stopped

- hosts: DBserver
  become: yes
  tasks:
  replace:
    path: /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
    regexp: "{{ item }}"
    replace: 'server "{{}}}" "{{}}"  check weight 1'
  with_items:
  - 'server "{{}}" "{{}}"  check weight 0' 


dictionary:
{ 'name': 'host1', 'key': 'ipxxx' }, { 'name': 'host2', 'key': 'ipxxxx' }, { 'name': 'host3', 'key': 'ipxxx' }, { 'name': 'host4', 'key': 'ipxxx' }
```

Comment: A couple resources you should read: [Working with inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html), [Working with playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks.html), [Delegation, rolling updates and Local Actions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html?highlight=rolling%20upgrades). To answer your question, you can place that var in a file and use it with [`vars_files`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#play) or add it to `group_vars/all.yml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this play.

```
---
- hosts: clients
  become: yes
  serial: 1
  tasks:

  - name: disable the haproxy server
    replace:
      path: /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
      regexp: "{{ item }}"
      replace: 'server {{ name }} {{ ip }}  check weight 0'
    with_items:
    - 'server {{ name }} {{ ip }}  check weight 1'

    delegate_to: deploy

  - name: stop the mariadb
    service:
      name: mariadb
      state: stopped

  - name: update mariadb
    apt:
      name: "{{ packages }}"
      state: latest
      update_cache: yes
    vars:
       packages:
       - mariadb-server
       - mariadb-client
       - mariadb-common

  - name: start the mariadb
    service:
      name: mariadb
      state: started

  - name: status mariadb
    shell: systemctl status mariadb
    register: server_status
  - name: debug
    debug:
       msg: "{{ server_status['stdout_lines'] }}"


  - name: enable proxy
    replace:
      path: /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
      regexp: "{{ item }}"
      replace: 'server {{ name }} {{ ip }}  check weight 1'
    with_items:
    - 'server {{ name }} {{ ip }}  check weight 0'

    delegate_to: deploy
```

I used the host_vars and that did the trick in combination with delegate_to.